# How I can execute commands using subprocess function

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to execute the commands in a python script :

1. Open cmd as administrator
2. `cd C:\elastic_stack\logstash-7.6.2`
3. `.\bin\logstash -f C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/flask_project_part2/project/logstash_file.conf`

This what I'm trying to do but it doesn't execute the last config file :

```
import os, subprocess 
from subprocess import *  
os.chdir("C:\\Users") 
cmd = subprocess.Popen(["runas", "/noprofile", "/user:Administrator", "|", "cd", "C:/elastic_stack/logstash-7.6.2"], shell=True)        
cmd.subprocess.run(["./bin/logstash", "-f", "C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/flask_project_part2/project/logstash_file.conf"], shell=True)
```

Comment: I have no experience using Python under Windows, but you seem to have a mix of forward and backward slashes as directory delimiters. Forward slashes are used on Unix systems and Windows is not Unix. Maybe check to see if you need to use Windows-specific delimiters.

Comment: @AlexReynolds I think that the delimiters are correct for windows but I suspect in the creation of the subprocess function itself if it replace the commands above or not.

Comment: `import *` is generally bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a combination of forward and backward slashes, but I am assuming that you have installed ELK on a windows machine:

Unfortunately I do not have access to a windows machine, so I didn't get a chance to test the code. But mainly it should be like this:

```py
import os
import subprocess

# desired path
target_dir = os.path.join("C:",os.sep,"elastic_stack",os.sep,"logstash-7.6.2")

# small check
if os.path.isdir(target_dir):
  os.chdir(target_dir)
else:
  print(" pathname does not refer to an existing directory")

# current working directory
print(os.getcwd())

# start logstash directly os.system will return the return code of the command if it's 0 means OK
os.system(".\\bin\\logstash -f C:\\Users\\Asus\\Desktop\\flask_project_part2\\project\\logstash_file.conf")

# if you need the output after you started logstash it will work ONLY in Python3

process = subprocess.run([".\\bin\\logstash", "-f", "C:\\Users\\Asus\\Desktop\\flask_project_part2\\project\\logstash_file.conf"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)


output = process.stdout
errors = process.stderr
```

PS: 
You can `os.sep` when constructing absolute or relative paths because in this way the separator is system agnostic.

`shell` argument  default is set to `False` and it means there is no system shell started up,  and if `shell=True` means system shell will first spin up.

Comment: Thank's for your help, I test it but unfortunately it doesn't work , I should  find my data in Elastic search , that's the result of the execution of the logstash config file.                                     PS: ELK is intalled and activate

Comment: when I run it I got this error:                                                                                              `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Le fichier spécifié est introuvable`